# Why is Stack Overflow missing the Tour, Chat, Contact, and Feedback links in the footer of the page?

Tags: support, status-review, hyperlinks, footer

On all the Stack Exchange sites (except Stack Overflow), I've noticed that when you scroll down to the footer of the page, you see a list of links to the Tour, Help, Chat, Contact, and Feedback pages, under the "[Site Name]" header.

Example from Super User:

[image]

But on Stack Overflow, those links are missing (except Help):

[image]

Why is this so?

Comment: For context, this question stems from [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/379765/513150) on MSE.

Comment: In my experience, IT people are allergic to consistency :)

Comment: I think you'll find that most are consistently inconsistent, @Gimby ; so they could defend that they are indeed consistent. ;)